# SonarQube ignoring AbstractValidator test classes

Tags: sonarqube, nunit, code-coverage, fluentvalidation

SonarQube ignores tests for AbstractValidators (FluentValidation.AspNetCore nuget package). In the coverage section, all RuleFor lines are marked as not covered.
What do I need to do, for the tests to be included in the coverage in SonarQube?
ReSharper shows the validator as being fully covered by tests.

The validator:

```
public class UserValidator : AbstractValidator<User>
{
    public UserValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(a => a.Name).NotEmpty();
        RuleFor(a => a.FirstName).NotEmpty();
    }
}
```

Test class:

```
public class UserValidatorTests
{
    [Test, TestCaseSource(nameof(User_InvalidData))]
    public async Task ValidationShouldFail(UserAndErrors testData)
    {
        var result = await new UserValidator().TestValidateAsync(testData.User!);

        Assert.IsFalse(result.IsValid);
        Assert.AreEqual(result.Errors.Count, testData.ErrorsCount);
    }

    [Test]
    public async Task ValidationShouldPass()
    {
        var request = new User
        {
            FirstName = "John",
            Name= "Doe"
        };
        var result = await new UserValidator().TestValidateAsync(request);

        Assert.IsTrue(result.IsValid);
        result.ShouldNotHaveAnyValidationErrors();
    }
            
    private static IEnumerable<TestCaseData> User_InvalidData()
    {
        yield return new TestCaseData(new User
        {
            User = new User(),
            ErrorsCount = 2
        });
        yield return new TestCaseData(new User
        {
            User = new User
            {
                Name = "Doe"
            },
            ErrorsCount = 1
        });
        yield return new TestCaseData(new User
        {
            User = new User
            {
                FirstName = "John"
            },
            ErrorsCount = 1
        });
    }       

    public class UserAndErrors
    {
        public User? User { get; set; }
        public int ErrorsCount { get; set; } = 0;
    }
}
```

User class:

```
public class User
{
    public string Name { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public string FirstName { get; set; } = string.Empty;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was the fact that the test project did not reference the *coverlet.msbuild* nuget package. Without it, SonarQube could not run the tests correctly and could not update the code coverage.